# After upgrade mailing and system status is blank (angular error)

Tags: upgrade, angular, error-page, status

I've just upgraded civicrm to 5.68.0. everything seems to be working as expected, except that the "System Status" page and creating new mailing. Both pages are empty and throw angluar error in console. [image]
Other angular pages like search kit and contact summary layout works fine and ther is not any errors in drupal 7 log.

After upgrading civicrm I had also another problem, that I have installed flexmail, but flexmail is core extension now. So I have installed flexmail twice. I uninstalled old flexmail and remove from default folder. This could be related to this problem. Can anyone help me what I can do? Can I somehow reinstall flexmail or whole civimail when they are core extension?